# Как вывести одну запись пользователя Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django, pycharm

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='post_files/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.title:
            return self.title
        return f"Post id: {self.id}"
```

html

```
{% for post in object_list %}
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="text-muted h7 mb-2"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{{ post.created_at }}</div>
                        <a class="card-link" href="#">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h5>
                        </a>

                        <p class="card-text">
                            {{ post.description }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="card-link"><i class="fa fa-gittip"></i> Like</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Comment</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link"><i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i> Share</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Выводятся все посты в один блок[image: нужно чтобы один пост выводился в один блок]

Answer (score 0):

Во views.py сделайте срез

```
object_list = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)[:1]
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).